# Why is this AttributeError happening?

Tags: python

Whenever I run my code, I get this error:

```py
line 39, in <module>
    for square in snake.body:
AttributeError: 'Snake' object has no attribute 'body'
```

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import sys
import random

pygame.init()
SW, SH = 800, 800
block_size = 50
FONT = pygame.font.Font("Nasa21-l23X.ttf", block_size * 2)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake!")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class Snake:
    def _init_(self):
        self.x, self.y = block_size, block_size
        self.xdir = 1
        self.ydir = 0
        self.head = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, block_size, block_size)
        self.body = [pygame.Rect(self.x - block_size, self.y, block_size, block_size)]
        self.dead = False


def drawGrid():
    for x in range(0, SW, block_size):
        for y in range(0, SH, block_size):
            rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, block_size, block_size)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, "#ffffff", rect, 1)


drawGrid()
snake = Snake()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, "green", Snake.head)
    for square in snake.body:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, "green", square)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(10)
```

It was supposed to make a grid with two green squares, but it just refuses to run.

Comment: The `__init__` method should have double underscores not single

Comment: I'd suggest updating the question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Because of Nasa21-123X.ttf, I can't run the program.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its what @IainShelvington said about the init method missing underscores and I also agree with ConstantinHong that it would be nice to have a MRE.